# Resource Manager spawns two applications when submitting job via REST API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, resourcemanager

When submitting my app via REST handle (as described in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_New_Application_API) I keep getting two applications with consequent numbers: one under the user specified in request ("me"), and one - under "yarn" user.

```
{
   "keep-containers-across-application-attempts":"false",
   "application-id":"application_1437150092132_66579",
   "application-name":"myapplication",
   "application-type":"YARN",
   "am-container-spec":{
   "environment":{
     "entry":[
        {
           "value":"etc/hadoop/conf<CPS>/etc/hadoop/conf<CPS>/etc/hadoop/conf<CPS>/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*<CPS>/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*<CPS>/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./<CPS>",
           "key":"CLASSPATH"
        }
     ]
  },
  "commands":{
     "command":"{{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -Xmx1000m net.mystreaming.hadoop.streaming2.MyStreaming -D mapreduce.job.queuename=root.default -mapper cat -reducer NONE -input /empty.seq -output /tmp/someoutput"
  }
   },
   "user":"me",
   "queue":"root.default",
   "unmanaged-AM":"false"
}`
```